# How to add text under every image?

Tags: html, css

I have problem with css. How to add text `My option` under every image?

Here is jsfiddle DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Leq3R/

My css code is here:

```
.product_des1 {
    width: 375px;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 72px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.product_des1:nth-child(2n+1) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.product_des1 img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.product_des1 span {
    color: #44a6e0;
}
#all {
    width: 1034px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to achieve.. is it this what you want? [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/Leq3R/5/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to add the same text under every image. You can achieve this only with css by using the following code:

```
.product_des1:after {
    content: "My option";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Leq3R/4/

So i'm practically adding some text after the container, witch will be displayed bellow the image.

Comment: Thanks. Can I replace `content: "My option"` to content from `<p>My option</p>` - from html code ?

Comment: No you can't. You can only have alpha numeric characters in `content`.

Comment: You can use the new `data()` thingy, but it's not supported well. You'll have to use Javascript

Comment: @user2659960 if you wish to interact furthermore with that text, to apply a class on it later or just to have a more flexible solution in the future I will advise you to use javascript to add a block of text under your image, and only then you'll be able to use the '<p>' tag, and inspect it more quickly in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

Change:

```
.product_des1 img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

To:

```
.product_des1 img {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:before`/`:after` pseudo selector to solve your problem.

I added the following css code to your code.

```
#all>div:before {
    content:"myOption";
    position:absolute; /* to show the content on the image */
    top:0;  /* pinning the content to top of this container */
    left:0;  /* keeping the content to left at the place of image */
}
#all>div {
    position:relative;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/Leq3R/5/)

Comment: Thanks. This selectors are not good in my case becouse I need `content:"myOption";` from my html code (example `<p>My Option</p>`) not from css

Comment: @user2659960 I agree with Caelea, you should do that dynamically.